How do you specify the type for a JSON import in TypeScript?
Given a TypeScript import statement like:
import icons from '/icons.json' with { type: 'json' };

How do you make sure TypeScript knows the type of icons at this point?
I've tried to create /icons.d.ts and /icons.json.d.ts with a export default typed named constant, but tsc doesn't seem to recognize these files.

Is icons.json available at compile time?

The filename needs to be in the format icons.d.json.ts and "allowArbitraryExtensions": true.
